# ExoPlayer InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 503 audio streaming

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, exoplayer

I am using ExoPlayer for audio streaming only, using OkHttpDataSourceFactory and I am facing with issue on Samsung Galaxy S5 Android Version 5.0.
The stream (http://88.85.99.43:8000/hitportal) is not working only with Mobile Data (3g/4g) and I am getting the following error:

`E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error. com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 503 at
com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:212) at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:123) at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:596) at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:295) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

Any ideas how to fix the issue?

Thanks.